# unable to upload with cordova filetransfer plugin on android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

The file chooser loads when i click on the button **My Picture** but nothing happens after i had chosen a file and clicked on **Upload** button. I want to be able to upload file onto server. I also want camera to appear in the list of the file chooser. I am using handlebars templates combined with ratchet.

Here is my code:
**html**

```
   <p><button class="btn btn-positive" id="inputIdbtn">My Picture</button></p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <button class="btn btn-positive" id="uploadbtn">Upload</button><div id="maphotodiv"></div>
   <input id="inputId" type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em" accept="image/*,capture=camera">
```

**javascript function**

```
  this.uploadToServer=function() {
            imageURI=document.getElementById("inputId").value;
            document.getElementById("maphotodiv").innerHTML="<p>processing...<p>"
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://...", win, fail, options);


        var win=function(r) {
            //console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            //console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            //console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            alert(r.response);
        };

        var fail=function(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        };  

};
```

Comment: Any error trace or error code could you post?

Comment: no error is shown. I am testing with a real device

Comment: Try remote debugging using chrome. I m sure that there may be some error in the console (like undefined variable) which may not pop up in device.

Comment: how do i enable remote debugging?

Comment: This shouold help - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Comment: ok, i will look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110993/discussion-between-paul-ngom-and-gandhi).